# How to postpone object deserialization, and just receive the JSON as a single large string object

Tags: c#, json

I have a small but maybe not-so-simple question.

I'm working on a Controller method which acts as a listener for JSON requests which will be coming into our system from another system. Ironically, I have no problems parsing these incoming requests into C# objects, and this is something I've already got working. However, at this point, I'm looking for a way to postpone parsing the objects, and just receive the JSON as a single, large string object. I have had no luck finding a solution yet.

This is the general format of my "listener" method:

```
public ActionResult Catch(string notification)
{
    ... do something with the notification string
}
```

I have seen solutions elsewhere which send a request to a certain URL and get back a string response that's a JSON string, but that isn't what I have to do here. The object is to have this method sitting there, waiting for any number of notification requests, quickly grab the JSON as a string, and then stuff it into a database queue with a date-timestamp.

The actual parsing of the string into valid objects would come later.

EDIT: I'm sorry I didn't make this clearer: I am not currently successfully receiving the string object. At this point, it is always null because C# attempts to parse it.

Comment: mmmm, What's the question? You're already saving them into the DB to be processed later, and you know how to process the string. So what would you like us to help you with?

Comment: @3dd: I've fixed the title to make the actual question clearer.

Comment: So just store the string as a string (ignore what the string actually represents) to the DB...what's the problem?

Comment: I agree with @kayson, store the string, create a job or scheduled task or something and process the strings when you need to

Comment: Edited question above: I'm not getting the string in correctly. @RobertHarvey - thanks for the title update.

Comment: @IliaKoulikov: It was me ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read it by yourself:

```
public ActionResult Catch()
{
    var reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream);
    var rawString = reader.ReadToEnd();

    //do something here.
}
```